# onLongClick animation with AsyncTask

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask, long-click

I would like to start animation when view is long clicked.

The code is as follows.

```
public class Example_Dialog extends Dialog implements AnimationListener{
    TextView    view_Description1 = null;
    View        view_Button1 = null;
    MessageCreateTask task;

    public Example_Dialog( Context context , int theme ){
        super( context , theme );

        setContentView(R.layout.infomation_dialog);

        view_Button1 = findViewById(R.id.common_dialog_button_1);
        view_Description1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.common_dialog_description_1);
        view_Description1.setHeight(0);

        view_Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                task = new MessageCreateTask(view_Description1);
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }


    class MessageCreateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        TextView textView;

        String messageOutput;
        int totalLineNum;

        public MessageCreateTask(TextView textView) {
            this.textView = textView;

            messageOutput = "";
            totalLineNum = 0;
        }

        @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for( int i= 0 ; i< 10 ; i++ ){
                messageOutput += "a" + "<br>";
                totalLineNum++;
            }
            return messageOutput;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            int dialogWidth     = 838;
            int dialogHeight    = 26*totalLineNum;

            textView.setWidth( dialogWidth );
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message));

            HeightAnimation hanime_open = new HeightAnimation(textView , 0 , dialogHeight );
            hanime_open = new HeightAnimation(textView , 0 , dialogHeight );
            hanime_open.setDuration(300);

            textView.startAnimation(hanime_open);
        }
    }
}


public class HeightAnimation extends Animation {

    int targetHeight;
    int startHeight;
    TextView textView;

    public HeightAnimation(TextView textView,int startHeight, int targetHeight) {
        this.textView = textView;
        this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
        this.startHeight = startHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newHeight = (int)(startHeight + (targetHeight - startHeight)*interpolatedTime);
        textView.setHeight(newHeight);

        if( (startHeight != 0) && (newHeight == 0) ){
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, ((View)textView.getParent()).getWidth(), parentHeight);
    }
}
```

The animation was not started with the above code, but it was started by replacing onclick with onlongclick like as below.

```
        view_Button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            public boolean onLongClick(View v){
                task = new MessageCreateTask(view_Description1);
                task.execute();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

I want to know the reason why animation does not start in case of onclick.

Comment: it´s just a guess, mabye it has something to do with the focus. I guess the focus is not at this view. Does it work with onClickListener() if you press the button twice?

Comment: Yes. If I press the button twice(double-tap), it works with onClickListener.

Comment: Then it´s a focus problem. Maybe it works if you call `view_button1.requestFocus()` after `setHeight()`

Comment: Thank you for the advice.I called requestFocus before starting animation but it did not change.

Comment: have you set in your XML layout: `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` ? or do this programmatically before calling `requestFocus()` : `view_button1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful advice!!   After putting setFocusableInTouchMode(true) ,it got the expected behavior!!

Comment: great I put an answer here...

Comment: Is it the specification of android that the focus is lost in longclick??

Comment: the focus is dependant on user Input, like on a web site. But it´s rarely documented inside the API wich view and why  this view is taking or not taking the focus and in what situation this happens. It´s really tricky...

Comment: I see. understood.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working with `onClickListener()` is, that the `view` hasn´t the Focus. So you Need to press the button twice or you have to use a `onlongClickListener()`. To make the `view` `clickable` the first time, do the following:

enable focusable in touch mode, wether in your XML layout as attribute:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

or programmatically after you have initialized the button:

```
view_button1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Then you can set the Focus to the view simply:

```
view_button1.requestFocus();
```